# Absolute path included in application

Tags: iphone, ios, security, testing, build

Am writing an application that has an emphasis on security with this in mind I run my test application through the "IDA Pro" tool. using this tool I was able to determine the absolute path of two of my source files so giving me the username of the build machine.

Does anyone know why two source files would be picked up like this out of hundreds? Is it the way that I have added these two files that is at fault?

Comment: Are you disassembling a debug or a release build? The version you ship shouldn't have any debug symbols in so the source file names should have been removed!

Comment: @deanWombourne thanks for reply, its a release version. I've just looked through my settings and both "Deployment Postprocessing" and "Strip Linked Product" were set to NO so I've switched them to Yes and am rechecking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deanWombourne answered the question with his comment, as it turns I was using a debug build

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is if the file's path is absolute and not relative in the project.  Find one of the offending files and:

- in Xcode 4, check the Utility view, File Inspector pane
- in Xcode 3, right click on the file and check the location on the first tab

If the file is linked with an absolute path instead of relative path, that may explain the difference.